# Mapping PUMA codes to county

Tags: geospatial, us-census, county

I'm looking for a mapping between PUMA codes (Public Use Microdata Area from the American Community Survey) to county. UMichigan has [this mapping](https://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/workshop/references/gis/puma2county.txt) (linked from [this](https://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/workshop/references/gis/Creating%20county%20level%20statistics%20from%20microdata%20files.pdf)), but there's no date so I'm not sure if it's still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/webatlas/pumas.html), "State partners define PUMAs once a decade after the decennial census." The most recent census was in 2010, so the current PUMA crosswalk would be the one based on the 2010 census.

UMichigan has [this crosswalk](https://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/workshop/utilities/p2c.equ) on their website, which appears to the the same as the one you linked to, although the URL is different. I got to it from [this page](https://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/census/Features/puma2cnty/). Based on the fact that it says "2010" on that page, I would expect that this is the 2010 crosswalk. You might want to you contact them and inquire, just to be sure.  [image]

They also provide historical [PUMA Equivalency Files](https://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/data/ref/PUMA/equiv.html) for 1980, 1990 and 2000.